# Lua - variations in the declaration of functions

Tags: function, lua

I'm quite new to Lua and slightly confused about how functions are declared.

These 2 variations seem to work: -

**1st variation**

```
test = {calc = function (x,y)
    z = x + y
    return z
end
}

result = test.calc (1,2)
print (result)
```

**Second variation**

```
test = {}

function test.calc(x,y)  
  z = x + y
  return z
end

result = test.calc (1,2)
print (result)
```

Are there any implications of selecting a particular variation?

Comment: no difference, correction for first variant : `test = {calc = function (x,y)  z = x + y  return z end }`

Comment: Also, use `local z = ...`.

Comment: Ok thanks..this resolves the mystery! So much to learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have exactly the same effect. Choose one or the other based on readability. (I prefer the second one.)

Comment: with `local test={}` there exists some difference. in this case funciton has no access to table itself. But it can be fixed by`local test test={}`

Answer (score 0):

Lua doesn't have function declarations. It has function definitions, which are expressions (1st variant) that produce a function value *when evaluated* at runtime. The other syntactical forms are effectively a combination of a function definition expression and an assignment.

In this 3rd variation, it is that plus an implicit 1st parameter `self`. It is intended to be used in a "method call" on a field. A method call is just an alternate form of function call that passes the table value holding the field (the function value) as an implicit 1st argument so the function can reference it, especially to access its other fields.

**3rd Variation: Method**

```
local test = { history = {} }

function test:calc(x,y)
  local z = x + y
  table.insert(self.history, { x = x, y = y })
  return z
end

print(test.calc)
local result = test:calc(1,2)
print(result)
print(test.history[1].x, test.history[1].y)
```